# Make AsyncFileUpload accepts only images files Asp.Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asyncfileupload

I am using `asyncfileupload` control, I want to accept only images. I used the accept attribute but it didn't work and used `OnClientUploadComplete` event to catch the content type and stop the uploading on server side, the event didn't fire and caused the `OnUploadedComplete` to not fire too! And I don't know how to stop it from uploading on the server side. I tried to check the `contentType` in `OnUploadedComplete` event, it fires and goes to 'else' but it doesn't show the message that it's supposed to show. Any suggestion?

C# code:

```
`protected void fileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fuImage.HasFile)
        {
            string contentType = fuImage.ContentType;
            if (contentType == "image/jpeg" || contentType == "image/gif"
              || contentType == "image/png")
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
                string fileUploadPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Resturant"), fileName);
                fuImage.SaveAs(fileUploadPath);

                var url = "~/images/Resturant/" + fileName;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "fileName",
                      "top.$get(\"" + hdfImagePath.ClientID + "\").value = '" + url + "';", true);
            }
            else
            {
            ucMessage1.MessageTitle = "Error Message";
            ucMessage1.MessageDetail = "Please Choose a valid image!";
            ucMessage1.MessageImage = "X";
            ucMessage1.Show();
        }
    }
}`
```

Design:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuImage" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="fileUpload_UploadedComplete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadedComplete`event fires on the server side when the file is successfully uploaded which means it cannot check the file extension before it being uploaded.

Comment: So, can I roll back the upload in this event? or even change the control background?

Comment: @RadwaAbdEllah I think you can, since you have the file name and the path. So you can check the format server side and if it is not what you want, delete the image (both the file and the db record, if any).

Comment: Now I want to change the `backColor` of the control to `red` if the file is not in the right format. I wrote that in the if loop but it doesn't change anything, can you help me with that?

`fuImage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`

Comment: @RadwaAbdEllah please ask this in a separate question.